# How to determine incorporated funds from the CFI

Tags: market-data, portfolio-selection

I am making a model for the acquisition of financial instruments, and it is sometimes important (for legal or tax reasons) to be able to determine whether an investment fund is incorporated (SICAV or something or that type) or not (e.g. a trust or FCP, etc.).

Looking at the CFI, it seems that for funds (class 'C') attribute 4 gives the following items:

`Security Type and Investors Restrictions
S: Shares
Q: Shares for QI
U: Units
Y: Units for QI`

Is that attribute supposed to answer the question? In particular what does "QI" mean in "Shares for QI"?

Otherwise, what would be correct approach?

Comment: This question is not really about quantitative finance thus probably shouldn't be here. However, the Open Data StackExchange (see https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) may be able to provide some insight on this topic.

Comment: That's a good point, and we might have a gap here. The data for finance (like ISIN, CFI, etc.) is so specialized that (at the moment) only people on  Quantitative Finance could answer them. Perhaps this question is a test and there would be a need for a new forum on that topic. Thats' something for meta, I guess?

Comment: Yeah, I have no experience in meta and haven't participated in anything there, may be worth a shot; I dunno. Not much to lose!